# buttons that are evenly spaced along the width of the screen

Tags: android, xml

I know there are a few questions with the same name but i have a bit of a different question. I already have it working, and when I have no color applied to the buttons, they are perfectly spaced across the bottom of the screen. When I apply a color, the gap between them fills. They still combined take up the screen, you cant tell though where one stops and another starts. I tried to apply left and right padding but that did not make any difference. Here is what I am working with.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/calm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".PiktuurMain" 

    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/buttonColor"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: pic]

Comment: if u can post a screen shot it would be better to predict ur problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a layoutMarginLeft and layoutMarginRight on the center button for about 10dp.